# Numpy slicing from variable

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I'm trying to slice a numpy array using a slice that is predefined in a variable. This works:

```
b = fromfunction(lambda x,y: 10*x+y, (5,4),dtype=int) # Just some matrix

b[1:3,1:3]
# Output:
# array([[11, 12],
#       [21, 22]])
```

But what I want to do is somthing like this:

```
slice = "1:3,1:3"
b[slice]
# Output:
# array([[11, 12],
#       [21, 22]])
```

It is not important to me what type the slice-variable has, I'm just using a string as an example. How do I save a slice-specifier like that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the built-in `slice` function

```
s = slice(1,3)
b[s,s]

ds = (s,s)
b[ds]
```

Answer (score 17):

[`numpy.s_` and `numpy.index_exp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html#numpy-s) provide a convenient way of doing this:

```
the_slice = numpy.index_exp[1:3, 1:3]
b[the_slice]
```

They can't do anything that you can't do with a combination of `slice`, tuples, `None`, and `Ellipsis`, but they allow you to use exactly the same syntax as you would use to slice an array (the only difference between `s_` and `index_exp` is that for a one-dimensional slice, `s_` returns a slice object, while `index_exp` wraps it in a tuple).