# Using a string to define Numpy array slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have an image array that has an X times Y shape of 2048x2088. The x-axis has two 20 pixel regions, one at the start and one at the end, which are used to calibrate the main image area. To access these regions I can slice the array like so:

```
prescan_area = img[:, :20]
data_area = img[:, 20:2068]
overscan_area = img[:, 2068:]
```

My question is how to define these areas in a configuration file in order the generalise this slice for other cameras which may have different prescan and overscan areas and therefore require a different slice.

Ideally, something like the strings below would allow a simple representation in the camera specific configuration file, but I am not sure how to translate these strings into array slices.

```
prescan_area_def = "[:, :20]"
image_area_def = "[:, 20:2068]"
overscan_area_def = "[:, 2068:]"
```

Maybe there is something obvious that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd prefer storing them as `slice` objects, or tuple equivalents.  `(slice(None), slice(None,20))` or `((None), (None,20))`.

Comment: I cannot store slice objects in image headers or configuration files, but I can store strings. If I understand correctly, I'd still have to translate those in string format to a ```slice``` object in my code?

Comment: True; but a slice object is easier to apply programatically: `np.arange(10)[ eval('slice(5,None)') ]`.

Comment: Related: [Numpy slicing from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616821/numpy-slicing-from-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
var1="img"
prescan_area_def = "[:, :20]"
```

and to use `eval`

```
prescan_area=eval(var1+prescan_area_def)
```

Comment: The other answers were along the lines of what I thought I'd have to do; parse the string into variables an use them to slice the array in the normal way. This is the type of answer I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: @James McCormac and for all future browsers: DO NOT USE THE `eval` SOLUTION. It is bad practice, and it may come back to bite you in the ass (in the form of a severe security vulnerability)

Answer (score 6):

You can parse the string and use `slice`. The following generator expression within `tuple` will create the slice objects for you:

```
tuple(slice(*(int(i) if i else None for i in part.strip().split(':'))) for part in prescan_area_def.strip('[]').split(','))
```

Demo:

```
In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: 

In [6]: a = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [8]: 

In [8]: prescan_area_def = "[:, :3]"

In [9]: a[:, :3]
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [15, 16, 17]])

In [10]: indices = tuple(slice(*(int(i) if i else None for i in part.strip().split(':'))) for part in prescan_area_def.strip('[]').split(','))

In [11]: indices
Out[11]: (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, 3, None))

In [12]: a[indices]
Out[12]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am all for doing things in a compact manner, but the length of the single line command makes this hard to keep track of. I think the shorter method using eval was what I was looking for.

Comment: this is the best answer, as it doesn't contain any dangerous code (see references made to the use of `eval` in other comments) and uses the proper access mechanisms (i.e. the `slice` object).

Answer (score 2):

For the love of all that's holy, DO NOT USE `eval` TO PARSE SIMPLE INPUT (see detailed rant below*).

### Answer for index/slice combo strings, eg `"[0, 1:5, :6, 13]"`

Expanding on @Kasravnd's excellent (but admittedly possibly confusing) answer, here's a function that will parse an ND string slice that contains both 1D slices and scalar indices:

```py
def parseSlice(sliceStr):
    return tuple((slice(*(int(i) if i else None for i in part.strip().split(':'))) if ':' in part else int(part.strip())) for part in sliceStr.strip('[]').split(','))
```

In plain English, here's what it does in order:

1. Break up `sliceStr` into parts, one `part` for every `,` in the original `sliceStr`
2. If a `part` contains a `:`, treat it as a slice

   i. Break up the `part` into indexes, one `i` for every `:` in the original `part`

   ii. Convert each `i` into an `int`

   iii. Feed the resulting list of `i` values into the builtin `slice` function (the `*` symbol lets you [pass a list of args to a function](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists))
3. Otherwise, treat the `part` as a scalar index and just convert the `part` to an `int`
4. Finally, wrap the resulting sequence of `int` and `slice` objects in a `tuple` and return it

### *The `eval` rant

There's really only two scenarios where someone would try to use `eval` to determine a slice from a string. Either a) the user is a raw beginner, and should be directed to use the proper non-string syntax to define their slices or b) the user is trying to parse a string provided by an external source, in which case they kiss any semblance of security goodbye. There [is no proven way to sanitize `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35804961/425458), there [is no completely safe way to use `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3513292/425458), and [eval really is amazingly dangerously](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

In short, probably don't actually ever use raw `eval` calls in your code. DEFINITELY don't use `eval` in any code you intend to release to the public. This is how severe vulns happen. In reality, 99% of the time there's a better solution than eval-ing anything (as there is to the OP's problem), and 99.9% of the time you can probably get away with using the much safer [`ast.literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/425458). Yes, there are some legit applications of `eval`. No, your use case almost certainly isn't among that .01%

Comment: I just tried your function with the text example you gave, and it failed with `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[0'`

Comment: @ProGamerGov A bit late on my part, but you're right! I had missed a `.strip('[]')` in the code. Guess I had tested the input without the outer brackets. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using regular expressions.

```
import numpy as np
import re

def slice_from_str(img, s):

    REGEX = r'\[(\d*):(\d*), (\d*):(\d*)\]'

    m = re.findall(REGEX,s)
    if m:
        # convert empty strings to None
        groups = [None if x=='' else int(x) for x in m[0]]
        start_x, end_x, start_y, end_y = groups
        x_slice = slice(start_x, end_x)
        y_slice = slice(start_y, end_y)

        return img[x_slice,y_slice]

    return []

img = np.random.rand(2048,2088)

prescan_area_def = '[:, :20]'
image_area_def = "[:, 20:2068]"
overscan_area_def = "[:, 2068:0]"

slice_from_str(img, prescan_area_def)
slice_from_str(img, image_area_def)
slice_from_str(img, overscan_area_def)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is quite a logical way to do it but it is much longer than the answer above using ```eval```, which I have accepted as the answer. Thanks!