# Partial slices in pytorch / numpy with arbitrary and variable number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Given an 2-dimensional tensor in numpy (or in pytorch), I can partially slice along all dimensions at once as follows:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(2*3).reshape(2,3)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> a[1:,1:]
array([[ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

How can I achieve the same slicing pattern regardless of the number of dimensions in the tensor if I do not know the number of dimensions at implementation time? (i.e. I want `a[1:]` if `a` has only one dimension, `a[1:,1:]` for two dimensions, `a[1:,1:,1:]` for three dimensions, and so on)

It would be nice if I could do it in a single line of code like the following, but this is invalid:

```py
a[(1:,) * len(a.shape)]  # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am specifically interested in a solution that works for pytorch tensors (just substitute torch for numpy above and the example is the same), but I figure it is likely and best if the solution works for both numpy and pytorch.

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised that I couldn't find a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer:**
Making a tuple of [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) objects does the trick:

```py
a[(slice(1,None),) * len(a.shape)]
```

**Explanation:**
`slice` is a builtin python class (not tied to numpy or pytorch) which provides an alternative to the subscript notation for describing slices.  [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12616901/3780389) to [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12616821/3780389) suggests using this as a way to store slice information in python variables. The [python glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) points out that

> The bracket (subscript) notation uses [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) objects internally.

Since the `__getitem__` methods for [numpy ndarrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) and [pytorch tensors](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor) support multi-dimensional indexing with slices, they must also support multidimensional indexing with slice objects, and so we can make a tuple of those slices that of the right length.

Btw, you can see how python uses the slice objects by creating a dummy class as follows and then do slicing on it:

```py
class A(object):
    def __getitem__(self, ix):
        return ix

print(A()[5])  # 5
print(A()[1:])  # slice(1, None, None)
print(A()[1:,1:])  # (slice(1, None, None), slice(1, None, None))
print(A()[1:,slice(1,None)])  #  (slice(1, None, None), slice(1, None, None))
```