# obtain matrix from a tensor in pytorch with arbitrary number of trailing dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch, slice

I have a pytorch tensor with an arbitrary number of dimensions : ...X,Y,Z

I would like to have a function such that I give a number C, and I get the ...,C,Y,Z

```
my_matrix = [:,:,C,:,:]
```

But I dont know how many trailing dimensions are before C, I saw an answer with using tuples of slices  but can seem to get it to work.
[Partial slices in pytorch / numpy with arbitrary and variable number of dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534732/partial-slices-in-pytorch-numpy-with-arbitrary-and-variable-number-of-dimensio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`ellipsis`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118508/9332187) will do the job:

```py
t = torch.randn(2, 3, 6, 5, 9, 3)
t[..., 4, :, :]

u = torch.randn(11, 4, 2, 7)
u[..., 2, :, :].shape
```